# Is this a known distribution?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

I came across the distribution on $(0,1]$ with the following density function
$$f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}$$

Is this a known distribution? 
Any references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the beta distribution with pdf

$$f(x,\alpha,\beta) = \frac{x^{\alpha - 1} (1-x)^{\beta - 1}}{C}$$ and parameters $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, $\beta = \frac{3}{2}$.  (where $C$ is an appropriate constant).